# How to remove captcha from Shopify wishlist

Tags: shopify

I currently have a Shopify website, whenever I try to add or remove any product from my wishlist it asks me to verify "I am not a bot" mainly captcha. This is giving me a bad user experience. Any idea as of how to remove it? Or displaying only once will also do.

Thanks

Comment: please share the website url

Comment: https://earthgarden.in